# In Oracle, how do I get a list of unique sites where they have been sampled for X number of years?

Tags: oracle, count, distinct, to-char

In Oracle, how do I get a list of unique sites where they have been sampled for X number of years AND have at least one data point every year? We need this to determine which sites to use for a long term trend analysis. I have been able to select a list of distinct sites where the first sample occurred over 36 years ago, but not sure how I would go about making sure each year had at least one data point. I have a feeling doing a COUNT over year might be a way to do this, but not sure of the exact language to get this done.

Here's the sample table (which contains the first data points of my larger dataset). The data for these continue until today.

```
drop table site_trends;
create table site_trends
 (
  site_id VARCHAR(30),
  date_time DATE,
  ANC VARCHAR(30)
);

insert into site_trends values('DR01', (TO_DATE('11/2/1979', 'mm/dd/yyyy')), 20.77);
insert into site_trends values('WR02', (TO_DATE('11/2/1979', 'mm/dd/yyyy')), 40.97);
insert into site_trends values('DR01', (TO_DATE('11/26/1980', 'mm/dd/yyyy')), 10.67);
insert into site_trends values('WR02', (TO_DATE('11/26/1980', 'mm/dd/yyyy')), 43.5);
insert into site_trends values('DR01', (TO_DATE('11/28/1981', 'mm/dd/yyyy')), 45.1);
insert into site_trends values('WR02', (TO_DATE('11/28/1981', 'mm/dd/yyyy')), 22.87);
```

Here's the code that adds the difference in years from today's date from the date sampled of any sites that were sampled 39+ years ago. I would use a DISTINCT(site_id) to provide me a list of just site_id's, but this shows a bit of how it works. Now I just need to make a condition that requires each year to have one data point per site.

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT site_id, date_time, ANC,
TO_CHAR(current_timestamp, 'yyyy') - TO_CHAR(date_time, 'yyyy') AS diff_year
FROM site_trends)
WHERE diff_year > 38
;
```

Comment: Do you mean that the sites should have at least one data point every year, up to and including the current year? Your example data doesn't fullfil that criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a bunch of ways to do it. I'd just group by site_id and year and do a count.

```
select * from (
    select site_id, 
           extract(year from sysdate) - extract(year from date_time) as diff_year,
           count(1) as num_years
    from site_trends
    group by site_id, extract(year from date_time)
) where diff_year > 38 and num_years = diff_year;
```